# Click button trigger input to appear with focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden search bar that is made visible when you click on a button. When the search bar appears I would like the input to already have focus, so the user can immediately start typing.

I'm using `$('#search-input').focus();` to try and achieve this on click but it isn't working.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/929153/). Click on the red box to trigger the search bar.

My Code:

```js
$('#search-btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#search-input').focus();
  $('#search-wrapper').toggleClass('visible');

  if ($('#region-wrapper').hasClass('visible')) {
    $('#region-wrapper').toggleClass('visible');
  }

  if ($('#region-select').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#region-select').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
#menu-side {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#search-btn {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

#search-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

#search-wrapper.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

#search-inner {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 35px 80px;
}

#search-input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

#search-submit {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  outline: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 21px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-side" class="clearfix">
  <button id="search-btn" class="float-right js-overlay"><i class="fas fa-search float-right"></i></button>

  <div id="search-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="search-inner" class="o-bdr-top">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" class="clearfix" action="">
          <button id="search-submit"><i class="fas fa-search float-right"></i></button>
          <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="What are you looking for?" name="s" class="float-left" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necesary to `#search-wrapper` be `hidden`? If i remove this property - all seems work fine.

Comment: @Smollet777 You catched the point, I removed also my answers (setTimeout based) because that's a dirty fix and nor resolve the problem root nor address to good programming patterns.

Answer (score 1):

> (From the official documentation) Take care to only use .focus() on elements that are visible.

You need just to wait for the toggle fired by `toggleClass()` to end so the `#search-input` input will be visible then you could perform the focus to the input.

Since `toggleClass()` method has no `complete` callback you could use `setTimeout()` for this like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#search-input').focus();
}, 100);
```

```js
$('#search-input').focus();

$('#search-btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#search-wrapper').toggleClass('visible');

  if ($('#region-wrapper').hasClass('visible')) {
    $('#region-wrapper').toggleClass('visible');
  }

  if ($('#region-select').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#region-select').toggleClass('active');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#search-input').focus();
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
#menu-side {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#search-btn {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

#search-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

#search-wrapper.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

#search-inner {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 35px 80px;
}

#search-input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

#search-submit {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  outline: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 21px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-side" class="clearfix">
  <button id="search-btn" class="float-right js-overlay"><i class="fas fa-search float-right"></i></button>

  <div id="search-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="search-inner" class="o-bdr-top">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" class="clearfix" action="">
          <button id="search-submit"><i class="fas fa-search float-right"></i></button>
          <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="What are you looking for?" name="s" class="float-left" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as in another comment below another answer both toggleClass and setTimeout haven't real timing you can rely on. Working with off screen elements or jquery promises ($("#myId").toggleClass('fadeOut',600).promise().done(...mymethod) is so much cleaner and solid

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini thanks for your intervention, `.promise()` require jQuery-UI I don't want to suggest it here, you could post a working answer that will be cool.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides on input being hidden initially and browsers prevent operation such as focus on hidden elements.
Common pratice, instead of using `display: none`, is to take the component `off screen` (IE: Fixed position with negative left and opacity === 0 or visibility hidden).

Using setTimeout (which in this case in undeterministic) is a **bad pratice** and should be avoided.

Comment: Why did you think `setTimeout()` is a bad practice for this case? _instead of using display: none_ where you see this role?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki simply because we cannot be sure of client’s internet speed / computing power. The delay may not be enough.

Comment: Your solution based on the change of `display: none` to opacity or visibility is hidden when the author already using `opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;` !!! could you give us a working fiddle instead?

Comment: Sorry my fault, also visibility prevent focus, so the offscreen hack work without change of visibility.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki toggleClass does not take always the same time. In fact jquery provides promises to work with when dealing with those methods. Also setTimeout does not guarantee the real time execution delay

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the use of `display` instead of `visibility/opacity` and toggling the classes, you could use simply `display: none` by default then toggle the display using the jQuery `toggle()` method then the focus will work:

```js
$('#search-input').focus();

$('#search-btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#search-wrapper').toggle();
  $('#search-input').focus();

  if ($('#region-wrapper').hasClass('visible')) {
    $('#region-wrapper').toggleClass('visible');
  }

  if ($('#region-select').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#region-select').toggleClass('active');
  }
  $('#search-input').toggleClass('active').focus();
});
```

```css
#menu-side {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#search-btn {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

#search-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

#search-inner {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 35px 80px;
}

#search-input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

#search-submit {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  outline: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 21px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-side" class="clearfix">
  <button id="search-btn" class="float-right js-overlay"><i class="fas fa-search float-right"></i></button>

  <div id="search-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="search-inner" class="o-bdr-top">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" class="clearfix" action="">
          <button id="search-submit"><i class="fas fa-search float-right"></i></button>
          <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="What are you looking for?" name="s" class="float-left" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```